# Is this possible?

Tags: ohms

I'm not very well versed in this at all. So bare with me! 
I have a thermo switch that turns a fan on at 212f = 186 ohms
And shuts it off at 194f = 243 ohms. My question is I would like to make this fan come on at around 194f = 243 ohms and off at 176f = 323 ohms. These values are from the manufacturer and are +-6%. Is there a way to make a plug and play inline "limiter" to do this. The switch powers a relay and then powers the fan on and off! How could this be accomplished?

Comment: (1) Your question title doesn't help anyone determine the subject of your post. (2) "_So bare with me._" is an invitation to strip. Do you men "bear" as in "to bear one another's burdens"? Could you edit both? Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Do you have a part number and link to datasheet for the switch? There isn't enough information there to determine how the switch works or how to modify the electronics. Even a photo of the circuit would give us some clues. Information **in the question**, please, and not in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do with a simple circuit is to shunt (put in parallel) the sensor with 919\$\Omega\$.

That will change the resistances at 176/194°F from 243/323 ohms to 192/239 rather than the 186/243 you would prefer, so they'll be a couple degrees off.

If you happen to have a -28 ohm series resistor lying around, a shunt with 1378 ohms would be exact, but they are really very hard to find these days.

Comment: And 910 ohms is a standard value that'll be close enough.